# Grads plotting data from different files (different points of time) in one 2D (height – time) plot

Tags: plot, noaa, grib, gfs, grads

I downloaded data from the american gfs weather modell (from ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014101812/master, edit date if you read more than 1 month later). Those are grib-files.

I am using grads to plot data and it works fine if I plot data from 1 timestep (=1 file) on a map.
So my first try was to open the first 2 files and to make a shaded plot showing areas with the same wind speed in the same color. What I get is an empty plot with correct axes.

```
'open gfs.t12z.mastergrb2f00.ctl'

'open gfs.t12z.mastergrb2f03.ctl'

'set dfile 1'

'set time 12Z17OCT2014'
'set gxout shaded'
'set lat 50'
'set lon 0'
'set lev 1000 200'
'set t 1 2'
'd sqrt(ugrdprs*ugrdprs+vgrdprs*vgrdprs)*1.9438'

'set dfile 2'
'set time 15Z17OCT2014'
'set t 1 2'
'd sqrt(ugrdprs*ugrdprs+vgrdprs*vgrdprs)*1.9438'
```

I am using opengrads – Grid Analysis and Display System (GrADS) Version 2.0.2.oga.2.

Anyone who can help me plotting data from different timesteps (= different files) into one plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one .ctl file to plot multiple data files.
I have done this with .gdat files, so I guess you will be able to do it with GRIB.
You should make new .ctl file using grads templates.

http://www.iges.org/grads/gadoc/templates.html

Basically, in dset line you will put a file name similar to

```
dset gfs.t12z.mastergrb2f%h2.grb
```

where %h2 represents 2 digit hour.